# How to ensure jquery-ui datepicker degrades gracefully to HTML5 date select?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm using a jquery-ui datepicker in a Rails 3 app. The datepicker is currently tied to a text field.

What is the best way to ensure that this degrades gracefully? i.e. it would make more sense to have the datepicker tied to an HTML5 date select field, but I'm having trouble implementing this as it doesn't seem to be readily supported by jquery.

Has anyone else run into this issue, and if so, how have you tackled it?

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[it still works](http://jsfiddle.net/QjgXb/) in the demo (no CSS though), even with `<input type="date">`.

[the new HTML5 input elements degrade to a `type="text"` if the browser doesn't support them](http://www.coreservlets.com/html5-tutorial/input-types.html). thus, you can add date-picker to a `type="date"` input.

and if you fear that there might be a "double-effect" where the natural date-picker goes with the jQuery date-picker, then take a look at [this article](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/createelementcheck.shtml) to detect if an element is supported, and selectively apply your date-picker.

Comment: hi jospeh, you are of course correct. My question was not very clear. If javascript is available, I would like the datepicker value to be displayed in a text field. If javascript is not available, the html5 date select should be displayed. I could simply provide a function that toggles the visibility of these elements (i.e., hides the date select, shows the text field). Are there other approaches that I should consider?

Comment: [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/QjgXb/1/), the datepicker is set if no JS, but when JS is available, we replace it with an input with jQuery's datepicker

Comment: looks perfect! I will play with this today. Thank you!